# How to stop my button going over the navbar?

Tags: css

The problem that I am facing is that my button is going over my navbar the mistake that I fear is the position: absolute option but I am unable to get any alternative of putting my button in the center of the image.

It's just a simple button with HTML:

```
<section class="home">
            <img src="assets/Front_Cover.png" alt="" class="home-image-img">
            <button class="home-button">Get Started</button>

        </section>
```

And CSS:

```
.home-button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 47%;
    left: 47%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #195154;
    color: white;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KipES.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
.home{
  position: relative
}
.home-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #195154;
    color: white;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Is .home is a div?

Comment: section with class button

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative;` not `position: absolute;`

> An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its
> normal position.
>
> Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a
> relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from
> its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into
> any gap left by the element.
> source [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:%7E:text=An%20element%20with%20position%3A%20relative,gap%20left%20by%20the%20element.)

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

That's the exact problem: if an element has the atribute `position: absolute;`, that element can appear on top of other elements.
You can try adjusting the "top" and "left" atributes to put the button exactly where you want to. Have in mind that by setting `position: absolute;` you can put the element wherever you want inside the parent element (in your case )

The other solution is to move the navBar.

Answer (score 0):

try adding z-index:1; in your navbar. It might solve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).